# Sharing desktop/network of another computer on LAN

Tags: networking, remote-desktop

I have a work laptop and a personal desktop, for the foreseeable future I'll be working from home and I would prefer working with a keyboard, mouse and multiple monitors I have on my desktop. The issue is that for my work I need to connect through a VPN on my laptop.

My ideal solution would be to somehow connect to internet on my desktop via my laptop as easily as possible (I would like to disconnect at the end of the day to use the desktop for personal use, and then easily re-connect the next day).

Another possible solution is to use some sort of desktop sharing, f.ex. TeamViewer. For TeamViewer specifically, I couldn't get it to work on my laptop (GUI wouldn't start), but I'm guessing there are other, maybe better solutions? One issue with desktop sharing is that it is a single window, so I cant make use of multiple monitors. The window also only has the resolution of the laptop (which is much smaller than the desktop).

What is the best way to achieve this? Should it matter, my desktop is Linux Mint 19.3 and the laptop is running Fedora 28.

Comment: Basically your laptop is the the network device through which the desktop traffic should pass. You can consider setting the default route for your desktop to the laptop's IP. To make such setup more manageable, you'd want to make the laptop IP fixed on your router.

Comment: @9000 The desktop is on a wired connection, so I think the default route has to be the router then?